# Cryptography: Mixing CBC and CTR?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I have some offline files that have to be password-protected. My strategy is as follows:

- Cipher Algorithm: AES, 128-bit block, 256-bit key (PBKDF2-SHA-256
  10000 iterations with a random salt stored plainly elsewhere)
- Whole file is divided into pages with page size 1024 bytes
- For a complete page, CBC is used
- For an incomplete page,

  - Use CBC with cipher text stealing if it has at least one block
  - Use CTR if it has less one block

With this setup, we can keep the same file size

IV or nonce will be based on the salt and deterministic. Since this is not for network communication, I reckon we don't need to concern about replay attacks?

Question: Will this kind of mixing lower the security? Would we better off just use CTR throughout the whole file?

Comment: Using salt and 10000 iterations is unreasonable overhead. KDF functions are already designed for key derivation. And using just an additional salt will be enough for most paranoids.

Comment: @PavelOgnev, using a salt alone only prevents a rainbow table from being built. But even without rainbow table, an average machine today with multiple cores and GPU can test at least some million passwords in a second. 10000 iterations can merely delay it to some degree. To be very secure, the key is to use a long password (e.g. > 15 characters)

Comment: This will deal a linear complication. So it's not a cryptographic approach. Attacker will need supercomputer instead of PC, but it will inevitably break a weak password.

Comment: So, if you are interested, 10000 iterations of KDF will compensate only 2 random symbols in password.

Comment: @PavelOgnev, yes, I am aware that 10000 iterations doesn't protect the passwords being recovered. However, there is no such completely secure system in the world. We just would like to employ every good and resource-friendly practice to ever improve the security. If an additional practice will only add a few more years to crack the passwords then it is already good to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better off just using CTR for the entire file. Otherwise, you're adding a lot of extra work, in supporting multiple modes (CBC, CTR, and CTS) and determining which mode to use. It's not clear there's any value in doing so, since CTR is perfectly fine for encrypting a large amount of data.

Are you planning on reusing the same IV for each page? You should expand a bit on what you mean by a page, but I'd recommend unique IV's for each page. Are these pages addressable somehow? You might want to look into some of the new [disk encryption modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory) for an idea on generating unique IV's

You also really need to MAC your data. In CTR for example, if someone flips a bit of the ciphertext, it'll flip the bit when you decrypt, and you'll never know it was tampered with. You can use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) or if you want to simplify your entire scheme, use [AES GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) mode, which combines CTR for encryption and GMAC for integrity

Comment: thanks for your input. I already have the combination of CBC, CTR and CTS in place and working properly. Since CBC seems to give me a sense of stronger encryption, that is why I wanted to include it in the strategy in the first place. But, generally, is there any known risk to use a mix of different modes? Will it help reducing the complexity of recovering the password or the key a bit?

Comment: CBC isn't any stronger than CTR mode. Both are NIST standards. CBC might leak less information if a nonce is reused, but you should guard against that. CTR is probably the preferred mode now, with Practical Cryptography recommending it, and newer modes like GCM using it. You still need a MAC with both CBC and CTR, and given your requirement for ciphertext stealing to prevent padding, I'd just use CTR for everything.

Comment: But in general, no, using these different modes won't lessen security any, provided you're doing everything else correctly.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments. But since you seem to have flexibility in choosing modes, you might really want to check out GCM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). It'll encrypt and authenticate the data in one go, has really good performance, and it'll let you authenticate additional metadata that might not need to be encrypted. It's also the only mode of operation specified for the NSA's Suite B http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_Suite_B_Cryptography

Comment: thank you very much for the additional information and links, that's exactly what I have been looking for. I will take a serious look on GCM and evaluate the additional complication introduced for my current model. However, it is very interesting that only GCM is mentioned in NSA Suite B Cryptography. What I want is only confidentiality. Is CBC mentioned in any (recent) recommended cryptography suite? Integrity, on the other hand, is out of our scope of protection. Aside, it seems GCM is the perfect choice when we would later allow network transfer of the files

Comment: GCM uses CTR mode for confidentiality, so I guess you could say Suite B allows CTR mode. But regardless, CBC, CTR, and GCM are all NIST approved modes of operation, and honestly you're perfectly fine choosing any of them. http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/current_modes.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to know about CTR mode. After you know them all you could happily apply a stream cipher in your situation:

- never ever reuse a data key with the same nonce;
- above, not even *in time*;
- be aware that CTR mode really shows the size of the encrypted data; always encrypting full blocks can hide this somewhat (in general a 1024 byte block takes as much as a single bit block if the file system boundaries are honored);
- CTR mode in itself does not provide authentication (for completion, as this was already discussed);

If you don't keep to the first two rules, an attacker will immediately see the place of the edit and the attacker will be able to retrieve data directly related to the plain text.

On a possitive node:

- you can happily use the offset (in, e.g., blocks) in the file to be part of the nonce;
- it is very easy to seek in files, buffer ciphertext and create multi-threaded code around CTR.

And in general:

- it pays off to use a data specific key specific sets of files, in such a way that if a key is compromised or changed that you don't have to re-encrypt everything;
- think very well about how your keys are used, stored, backed up etc. Key management is the hardest part;